# Draw a line between 2 JCheckBox objects in Java Eclipse WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jcheckbox, windowbuilder

I have some checkboxes on a form and I want them to be connected by single lines. Is there some easy way to do this? Since I'm using WindowBuilder and the objects could move around as the form size changes, I can't just put a graphic on the screen.

Specifically, I have 4 checkboxes representing bases on a baseball diamond, in a diamond pattern. I want the base paths connecting them to be straight lines.

Comment: *"Is there some easy way to do this?"* - No

Comment: Having spent some time thinking about it, basically you need a component (probably a `JPanel`), you'll need to override it's `paintComponent` method and draw a line between the components. You may need to specify the order in which the components should be joined

Comment: This sounds like above my skill level. Maybe a better approach would be to make multiple pictures of the diamond for the various possibilities, and display the appropriate one based on which bases are occupied.

Comment: That would actually be more difficult to manage and maintain, especially across different platforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the basic concept is:

- You need to be able to calculate the centre position of a component, based on it's location within the parent container
- You need someway to be able to paint beneath the components, so the line isn't rendered over the top of them.

This would suggest that the `JCheckBox`s need to be contained within the same component/container, which would just make it simpler to work with.

From there, you'd override the component's `paintComponent` method, calculate the centre positions of the source and target components/check boxes and draw a line between

For example...

[image: Connected points]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JCheckBox[] checkBoxes;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;

            checkBoxes = new JCheckBox[4];
            for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
                checkBoxes[index] = new JCheckBox();
                checkBoxes[index].setOpaque(false);
                checkBoxes[index].setHorizontalAlignment(JCheckBox.CENTER);
            }

            // Base
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(checkBoxes[0], gbc);

            // First
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(checkBoxes[1], gbc);

            // Second
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(checkBoxes[2], gbc);

            // Third
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(checkBoxes[3], gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected Point center(Rectangle bounds) {
            Point point = new Point();
            point.x = bounds.x + (bounds.width / 2);
            point.y = bounds.y + (bounds.height / 2);
            return point;
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            Point from = center(checkBoxes[0].getBounds());
            for (int index = 1; index < checkBoxes.length; index++) {
                Rectangle bounds = checkBoxes[index].getBounds();
                Point to = center(bounds);
                g2d.drawLine(from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y);
                from = to;
            }
            Point to = center(checkBoxes[0].getBounds());
            g2d.drawLine(from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Caveat: Because of the way painting works in Swing, when a child component is updated/repainted, it's possible that the parent component won't be notified/painted.  So, any changes you make to any of the child components, which might affect the position of the lines, needs to also force a `repaint` of the parent component as well

And no, you can't do this through Window Builder, you're going to have to get your hands dirty to make this work properly

Comment: This is good but won't really work for a baseball diamond. As you resize the form, it moves the boxes around so it is no longer square. The whole thing needs to retain the square dimensions.

Comment: @MichaelT Then either change the layout manager or combine two or more, so that the `TestPane` is discouraged from been resized